# Crystal Reports TestConnection Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports app that I am loading through VS2010. I have the CR Runtime 13.0.2 loaded on my machine. When I run the app using debug, it works fine. (Great in fact.) But when I install the application that is built (even on the VERY same dev machine.) the TestConnection line comes back false, which indicates to me that it's not connecting properly to my database.

If I don't put this code in there, the app prompts for login credentials at THIS line:
Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument1

But the DB Name and Server Name are incorrect and grayed out, and anything that I put in UserName and PW doesn't work.

I've searched google and tried any number of "fixes" and NOTHING gets it to work.

I also used database expert to "update" my datasource, and ran a "verify database" from design mode and still the same thing happens.

Here is my code:

```
Private Function ConnectReport(sDatabaseFile As String, _serverName As String, ReportDocument1 As ReportDocument)
    ReportDocument1.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sqlAdmin2008", _serverName, sDatabaseFile, True)


    For x As Integer = 0 To ReportDocument1.DataSourceConnections.Count - 1
        ReportDocument1.DataSourceConnections(x).SetConnection(_serverName, sDatabaseFile, "sa", "sqlAdmin2008")
    Next

    For Each cTable As Table In ReportDocument1.Database.Tables
        If cTable.Name <> "Command" Then
            SetTableConnectionInfo(cTable, sDatabaseFile, _serverName)
        End If
    Next

    For Each obj As ReportObject In ReportDocument1.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects

        If obj.Kind = ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then
            Dim subReport As SubreportObject = CType(obj, SubreportObject)
            Dim subReportDocument As ReportDocument = ReportDocument1.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName)
            ConnectReport(sDatabaseFile, _serverName, subReportDocument)
        End If
    Next

End Function

Private Function SetTableConnectionInfo(cTable As Table, sDatabaseFile As String, _serverName As String)
    Dim logonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = cTable.LogOnInfo
    Dim connInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()

    connInfo.DatabaseName = sDatabaseFile
    connInfo.ServerName = _serverName
    connInfo.UserID = "sa"
    connInfo.Password = "sqlAdmin2008"
    'connInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL
    logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo

    cTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo)

    If cTable.TestConnectivity = False Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("Cannot connect Crystal Reports to Database.")
    End If

    cTable.Location = sDatabaseFile & "." & "dbo" & "." & cTable.Location


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you need to pass the table in as a reference like this.

```
Private Function SetTableConnectionInfo(ref cTable As Table, sDatabaseFile As String, _serverName As String)
```